# Jquery first word CAPs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using wordpress `the_date()` function to get the post date , 
and it returns me

```
<h2 class="the_date>Friday, August 12, 2011</h2>
```

What I need is to have the friday to be caps without effecting other words aka FRIDAY, August 12, 2011.

Can this be done with jQuery or javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your WordPress theme, you could use

```
<?php strtoupper(the_time('l')) . ", " . the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
```

instead of `the_date()` to get your desired output.

**Update**

jQuery solution if you wish to go that route:

*HTML*

```
<h2 class="the_date">Friday, August 12, 2011</h2>
```

*jQuery*

```
var the_date = $('.the_date').html().split(', ');
the_date = [the_date[0].toUpperCase(), the_date.slice(1).join(', ')].join(', ');
$('.the_date').html(the_date);
```

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tcA4y/

**Updated jsFiddle demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/tcA4y/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer , for a reason I can't use the_time() because I want to have only one instance of the date.
The jQuery example is great but how to do if I have a list of items of the class aka

<h2 class="the_date">Friday, August 12, 2011</h2>
<h2 class="the_date">Friday, August 12, 2011</h2>
<h2 class="the_date">Friday, August 12, 2011</h2>
how can I target all ?

Comment: @ELzarei: You can use `the_date()` then and just use the jQuery solution instead to update all your dates with the `the_date` class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , for a reason I can't use the_time() because I want to have only one instance of the date.
The jQuery example is great but how to do if I have a list of items of the class aka

<h2 class="the_date">Friday, August 12, 2011</h2>
<h2 class="the_date">Friday, August 12, 2011</h2>
<h2 class="the_date">Friday, August 12, 2011</h2>
how can I target all ?

Comment: when I use this code with multiple lines , I just do all with the same date

Comment: @ELzarei: The updated jsFiddle was just to show / prove that it updates the multiple lines with different dates, if need be.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using JavaScript's [`String.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase):

```
var date = "Friday, August 12, 2011";
var pieces = date.split(" ");
pieces[0] = pieces[0].toUpperCase();
alert(pieces.join(" "));
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/hC3JW/)

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind, this is pseudocode, not checked for syntax/runnability.

```
var myString = the_date()
myString = myString.SubString(0, myString.indexOf(',')).ToUpperCase() + myString.Substring(myString.indexOf(','));
```

The syntax may be off a bit, and you may need to add/subtract 1 on either of the indexOf calls to include the proper character, but this method should work.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use either substr/substring or split/join. I'd be inclined to use split/join:

```
// breaks into array based on comma
var dt = 'Friday, August 12, 2011'.split(','); 
// reassign 0 index to upper case (so Friday, in this case)
dt[0] = dt[0].toUpperCase();
console.log( dt.join( ',' ) ); // FRIDAY, August 12, 2011
```

And here's the substr version:

```
var dt = 'Friday, August 12, 2011';
// I'm using 'y' here because days which do not end in Y are very rare.
var yindex = dt.indexOf("y");
     // everything before and including y to upper case
dt = dt.substr(0, yindex + 1).toUpperCase() + 
     // then add the balance to the end.
     dt.substr( yindex + 1);
console.log( dt );
```

Answer (score 0):

[javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp) can do this.  you can substring the first word out, capatalize it, and put it back.